# Animating obj files with OBJLoader in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I currently have to do an animation with obj files. I want to rotate horizontally the loaded ribs. Is it just POSSIBLE to animate obj files ? If so, how do you do that ? I search all over the web, the only animation examples I found were made using JSONLoader, wich I don't use. Here is my code :

```
window.onload = function() {
 var container, stats;
 var camera, scene, renderer, object;

 var windowHalfX;
 var windowHalfY;

init();
animate();


function init() {

    width = 500;
            height = 500;

            windowHalfX=width/2;
            windowHalfY=height/2;

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, width / height, 1, 2000 );
    camera.position.z = 300;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
    scene.add( ambient );

    var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
    directionalLight.position.set( 0, 1, 1 );
    scene.add( directionalLight );

    var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();
            for ( var i = 1; i < 13; i ++ ) {
              var chem = './three/obj/Cotes/left/CG';
              if (i<10) {
                 var nomcote = chem+'0'+i+'.obj';
                 var matcote = chem+'0'+i+'.mtl';
              }
              else{
                 var nomcote = chem+i+'.obj';
                 var matcote = chem+i+'.mtl';
              }
              loader.load( nomcote, matcote, function ( object ) {
                 object.position.y = - 70;
                 object.name = "cotesG"+i;
         scene.add( object );
              } );
           }
           for ( var i = 1; i < 13; i ++ ) {
              var chem = './three/obj/Cotes/right/CD';
              if (i<10) {
                 var nomcote = chem+'0'+i+'.obj';
                 var matcote = chem+'0'+i+'.mtl';
              }
              else{
                 var nomcote = chem+i+'.obj';
                 var matcote = chem+i+'.mtl';
              }
              loader.load( nomcote, matcote, function ( object ) {
                 object.position.y = - 70;
                 object.name = "cotesD"+i;
         scene.add( object );
              } );
           }
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );

            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );

    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

}

    function onWindowResize() {
            windowHalfX = width / 2;
    windowHalfY = height / 2;

    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( width, height );
    render();
}

function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();

}

function render() {
          // camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        renderer.render( scene, camera );

}
  }
```

Comment: See the obj file format specification. It is used for static data only. Nevertheless, if you have some separate objects that you only want to transform in simple ways, you can do so as you would move/rotate/scale any other parent/child object combination.

Comment: I've been trying to do this too, yet I find the OBJLoader doesn't seem to let us affect the loaded mesh outside of the loading function. How can we address the loaded mesh?